# Special Matrices

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, stix

Good morning

My Professor wrote this matrices on LaTeX, but I don't understand how he succeded in.

[image]

Could someone help me? Please, Thanks.
P.S.: I state that I use `stix` and `\documentclass{book}` and I'd like to learn `TikZ`.

Comment: Take a look at the very easy-to-use package `nicematrix`.

Answer (score 7):

This is easy with standard LaTeX but as [projetmbc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6880/projetmbc) suggests, take a look at the `nicematrix` package too, it offers many more possibilities.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
  A=\left(\begin{array}{cccc|ccc}
    0      & 0      & \cdots &\multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & a_{1(j+1)} & \cdots & a_{1n_{\mathstrut}}\\\cline{5-7}
    0      & 0      & \cdots & 0                    &            &        & \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots               &            &  A'    & \\
    0      & 0      & \cdots & 0                    &            &        &
  \end{array}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** As [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) suggested I changed `a_{1n}` for `a_{1n_{\mathstrut}}` that sets a better vertical spacing.

Comment: +1. I'd be tempted, though, to change `a_{1n}` in row 1 to `a_{1n_{\mathstrut}}` to increase the vertical separation to the `\cline` rule ever so subtly.

Comment: @Mico, I agree. I just made an edit :-P

Comment: `\def\arraystretch{1.2}` or `\\[1pt]` achieve the same effect.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, I prefer Mico's solution or `\\[1pt]` because it's only the space in the first line which needs to be slightly changed.

Answer (score 6):

With `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\[
  A=\begin{pNiceMatrix}[right-margin]
    0      & 0      & \cdots & 1 & a_{1(j+1)} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
    0      & 0      & \cdots & 0 & \Block[borders={top,left}]{3-3}<\Large>{A'} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
    0      & 0      & \cdots & 0       \\
  \end{pNiceMatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Several compilations?? How many, more or less? Under the hood, what do you mean with HOOD?? Thx.

Comment: LaTeX gives a message when another compilation is needed. Some tools, such as `latexmk` automatically do the right number of compilations. "under the hood" is a English expression. Here I mean that `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes even if the final user does not see those nodes and even has never used Tikz explicitely.

Comment: Ok, Thank you so much. Best Regards

Answer (score 3):

With `+pmatrix` from `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ A=
\begin{+pmatrix}[vline{5}={2-Z}{solid},hline{2}={5-Z}{solid}]
    0      & 0      & \cdots & 1 & a_{1(j+1)} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
    0      & 0      & \cdots & 0 & \SetCell[r=3,c=3]{c,m} A'\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
    0      & 0      & \cdots & 0       \\
\end{+pmatrix},\quad
B=
\begin{+pmatrix}[vline{5}={2-Z}{solid},hline{2}={5-Z}{solid}]
    0      & 0      & \cdots & 1 & b_{1(j+1)} & \cdots & b_{1n}\\
    0      & 0      & \cdots & 0 & \SetCell[r=3,c=3]{c,m} B'\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
    0      & 0      & \cdots & 0       \\
\end{+pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]